# Sum of the greatest value in one column, plus the sum of the other values in another column

Tags: excel-formula

Consider the following sheet/table:

```
   A    B
1  90   71
2  40   25
3  60   16
4  110  13
5  87   82
```

I want to have a general formula in cell `C1` that sums the greatest value in column `A` (which is `110`), plus the sum of the other values in column `B` (which are `71`, `25`, `16` and `82`). I would appreciate if the formula wasn't an array formula (as in requiring Ctrl + Shift + Enter). I don’t have Office 365, I have Excel 2019.

#### My attempt

Getting the greatest value in column `A` is easy, we use `MAX(A1:A5)`.

So the formula I want in cell `C1` should be something like:

```
=MAX(A1:A5) + SUM(array_of_values_to_be_summed)
```

Obtaining the values of the other rows in column `B` (what I called `array_of_values_to_be_summed` in the previous formula) is the hard part. I've read about using `INDEX`, `MATCH`, their combination, and obtaining arrays by using parenthesis and equal signs, and I've tried that, without success so far.

For example, I noticed that `NOT((A1:A5 = MAX(A1:A5)))` yields an array/list containing ones (or `TRUE`s) for the relative position of the rows to be summed, and containing a zero (or `FALSE`) for the relative position of the row to be omitted. Maybe this is useful, I couldn't find how.

Any ideas? Thanks.

#### Edit 1 (solution)

I managed to obtain what I wanted. I simply multiplied the array obtained with the `NOT` formula, by the range `B1:B5`. The final formula is:

```
=MAX(A1:A5) + SUM(NOT((A1:A5 = MAX(A1:A5))) * B1:B5)
```

#### Edit 2 (duplicate values)

I forgot to explain what the formula should do if there are duplicates in column `A`. In that case, the first term of my final formula (the term that has the `MAX` function) would be the one whose corresponding value in column `B` is smallest, and the value in column `B` of the other duplicates would be used in the second term (the one containing the `SUM` function).

For example, consider the following sheet/table:

```
   A    B
1  90   71
2  110  25
3  60   16
4  110  13
5  110  82
```

Based on the above table, the formula should yield 110 + (71 + 25 + 16 + 82) = 304.

Just to give context, the reason I want such a formula is because I’m writing a spreadsheet that automatically calculates the electric current rating of the short-circuit protective device of the feeder of a group of electric motors in a house or building or mall, as required by the article 430.62(A) of the US National Electrical Code. Column `A` is the current rating of the short-circuit protective device of the branch-circuit of each motors, and column `B` is the full-load current of each motor.

Comment: Another option is =MAX(A1:A5)+SUM(B1:B5)-VLOOKUP(MAX(A1:A5),A1:B5,2,FALSE). But Both this and your solution assumes that the values in column A are unique. Example, if there are 2 rows in Column A with value 110. Not sure what the expected result for such a case is and if such a case actually exists.

Comment: @AnupamChand Whoops, I forgot to explain that. I’ve edited my question to consider that. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
=MAX(A1:A5)
  +SUM(B1:B5)
  -AGGREGATE(15,6,(B1:B5)/(A1:A5=MAX(A1:A5)),1)
```

[image]

Based on @Anupam Chand's hint for max-value-duplicates there could also be min-value-duplicates in column B for corresponding max-value-duplicates in column A. :) This formula would account for that

```
=SUM(B1:B5)
   +(MAX(A1:A5)-AGGREGATE(15,6,(B1:B5)/(A1:A5=MAX(A1:A5)),1))
   *SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5=MAX(A1:A5))*(B1:B5=AGGREGATE(15,6,(B1:B5)/(A1:A5=MAX(A1:A5)),1)))
```

[image]

Or with @Anupam Chand's shorter and better readable and overall better style :)

```
=SUM(B1:B5)
  +(MAX(A1:A5)-MINIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,MAX(A1:A5)))
  *COUNTIFS(A1:A5,MAX(A1:A5),B1:B5,MINIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,MAX(A1:A5)))
```

The explanation works for bot solutions:

The `SUM`-part just sums the whole list.

The second line gets the max-value for column A and the corresponding min-value of column B for the max-values in column A  and adds or subtracts it respectively.

The third line counts, how many times the corresponding min-value for the max-value occurs and multiplies it with the second line.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the first and second formulas and both worked. The third one uses MINIFS which Excel 2019 doesn't have. For some reason, the second formula you posted was in German (I think) and used semicolons.

Comment: Woops, i forgot to convert the formula to english (you are right, it was german). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
=MAX(A1:A5)+SUM(B1:B5)-MINIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,MAX(A1:A5))
```

What we're doing is adding the max of A to all rows of B and then subtracting the min value of B where A is the max.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula uses the MINIFS function, which is only available for Excel 365, which I don't have. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the following LET-Formula

```
=LET(A,A1:A5,
B,B1:B5,
MaxA,MAX(A),
MinBExclude, MINIFS(B,A,MaxA),
sumB1,SUMPRODUCT(B*(A=MaxA)*(B<>MinBExclude)),
sumB2,SUMPRODUCT(B*(A<>MaxA)),
MaxA +sumB1+sumB2
```

`A` and `B` are shortcuts for the two ranges

`MaxA` returns the max value for A (110)

`MinBExclude` filters the values of column B by the MaxA-value (25, 13, 82) and returns the min-value of the filtered result (13)

`sumB1` returns the sum of the other MaxA values from column B (26 + 82)

`sumB2` returns the sum of the values from B where value in A <> MaxA (71 + 60)

and finally the result is returned

If you don't have Excel 365 you can add helper columns for MaxA, MinBExclude, sumB1 and sumB2 and the final result

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have Office 365. I’ve just clarified this in the post.

Comment: If you use helper columns per each "parameter" and its formula (except `A` and `B`) you can achieve the same result - but have to replace `A` and `B by their ranges within the formulas.